# Adding Select2 class from JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

In my web application, I'm adding new rows to the table from JavaScript.

There is an `<select>` element in the row and for the `<options>` I'm loading data from the ViewBag.

Also, I want to add Select2 class to the same `<select>` element.

So I tried doing,

```
'<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select Select2 ItemId" data-id= '+counter+' name="Item_Id[' +
  counter +']" id="ItemId[' + counter +']" required="required" ' + "</select>"
```

But it doesn't apply to the class correctly.

I want help from you to fix this issue.

Here is my full code.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>MEASURE BY</th>
        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
        <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 var counter = 1;

 var dropdownOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Item_ID));

 $(function () {

   $("#add").click(function () {
     var newRow = $(
       '<tr id="tablerow' +
       counter +
       '" class ="poSet"> ' +
       "<td>" +
       '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
       counter +
       "</strong></label>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="40%">' +
       '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
       counter +
       ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
       "</select>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       "<td>" +
       '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
       counter +
       ');">x</button>' +
       "</td>" +
       "</tr>"
     );

     var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); // Find the <select> element in the new row

     // Populate the <select> element with options

     dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {

       var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
       selectElement.append(optionElement);
       optionElement.select2();

     });
     newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

     counter++;
     return false;
   });

 });
```

hi @mina, I tried your code and it fixed the issue, but still there is some issue in the view, could you help me to resolve this also?

[image]

When I 1st add the data  element width comes with the default and then onwards it changes.

There is also an issue in the view of the select 2 combo box. I think missing a form-control class or something, it looks like a combo box without the CSS.

Comment: Pretty sure that the `Select2` class gets added by the script itself, when you initialize this on a select element. And if that class is _already_ present, presumably it does nothing (because why do the same work twice.)

Comment: `optionElement.select2()` - why are you trying to call this on an _option_ element?

Comment: `.select2()` is supposed to be called on a `select` element, as @CBroe is implying.

Comment: @CBroe and you.  thanks for pointing the issue.

Comment: No, you don't get to ask another question on top of another question that's already been answered. If you have a new question, as a new question. You can link to this one as reference, but every question should be able to stand alone in terms of code and explanation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sure. Thanks I will ask another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I notice in your code, you are initialize `select2` on each option not on the select itself.

```
$(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
    var newRow = $(
       '<tr id="tablerow' +
       counter +
       '" class ="poSet"> ' +
       "<td>" +
       '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
       counter +
       "</strong></label>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="40%">' +
       '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
       counter +
       ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
       "</select>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       "<td>" +
       '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
       counter +
       ');">x</button>' +
       "</td>" +
       "</tr>"
     );
    
    var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); 

    dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {
      var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      selectElement.append(optionElement);
    });

    newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

    selectElement.select2();

    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here you initialize `select2` in the select after adding the options.

Comment: Hi thank you for your explanation and the guide, I tried and it fixed 50% of my issue, there are a few things that still need to fix. So I updated my question,. Can you look at it?  Thank you

Comment: @DevBeginner, It would be better to ask new question about the new issues.

Comment: Sure , I will ask another